# Laravel - How to resolve Error 404 - Page not found in Dropdown list filter

Tags: jquery, laravel

In my Laravel-5.8, I am working on Leave Application. I want to filter the leave by each employee.

Controller

```
public function index($id = "")
{
try {  
    $id                       = "";
    $employeeId          = DB::table('hr_employees')->select('id')->pluck('id');
    $employeefilters             = HrEmployee::whereIn('id', $employeeId)->get();

     $leaves = Leave::where('employee_id', $id)->get();
    return view('admin.leaves.index')
                ->with(['leaves' $leaves)
                ->with('employeefilters', $employeefilters)
                ->with('selectedEmployeeFilter', $id);

    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Session::flash('error', 'Action failed! Please try again');
        return back();
        }              
    }
```

view: index.blade

```
          <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <select class="form-control select2bs4" data-placeholder="Select Employees tabindex="1" id="filter">
                    <option value="select">Select Employees</option>
                @foreach($employeefilters as $employeefilter)
                    <option value="{{$employeefilter->id}}" @if($selectedEmployeeFilter == $employeefilter->id) selected @endif>{{$employeefilter->employee_code}}</option>
                @endforeach
                 </select>
            </div>
          </div>                 


  <table class=" table table-bordered table-striped table-hover datatable">
    <tbody>
                @foreach($leaves as $key => $leave)
                <tr>

               </tr>
                @endforeach 
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#filter").change(function(e){
            if ($(this).val()=== "select" ){

                var url = "{{route('admin.leaves.index')}}/"
            }
            else{
                var url = "{{route('admin.leaves.index')}}/" + $(this).val();
            }

            if (url) {
                window.location = url;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
  </script>
```

route/web.php

```
  Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.', 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () 
  {
        Route::resource('leaves', 'LeavesController');
  });
```

When I run php artisan route:list

I got this as the route

> admin.leaves.index

That is,

> admin/leaves

I want the page to be blank on default.

Now the problem is that when I select the employee from the dropdown, I expected it to load all the leaves of that particular employee. But I got this error:

> Error 404 - Page not found

How do I resolve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are using **Employee id** on **Leave** Model that's why you are getting 404.

if you want to show Leaves of your Employee id you should define a route for it (like **admin/leaves/by/{empId}**) and link it to a new method in LeaveController (like **indexByEmployee**)